# Error: backingFormData.forEach is not a function, nextjs 13

Tags: debugging, next.js13

I'm trying to use the new feature 'Server action' in Nextjs 13, but I get 'Error: backingFormData.forEach is not a function' when submitting a form with a server action

```
import { useState} from 'react'

export interface Product {
  id?: number;
  product: string;
  price: string;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://64bda1242320b36433c7c958.mockapi.io/product",
    {
      cache: "no-cache",
    }
  );

  const addProductToDatabase = async (e: FormData) => {
  "use server"
  //   const product = e.get("product")?.toString();
  //   const price = e.get("price")?.toString();
  //   if (!product || !price) return;
  //   const newProduct: Product = {
  //     product,
  //     price
  //   } 
  //   await fetch('https://64bda1242320b36433c7c958.mockapi.io/product', {
  //     method: 'POST',
  //     body: JSON.stringify(newProduct),
  //     headers: {
  //       'Content-Type':'application/json'
  //     }
  //   })
  };
  const products: Product[] = await res.json();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center">
        Testing product server function
      </h1>

      <form
        action={addProductToDatabase}
        className="flex flex-col gap-5 max-w-xl mx-auto p-5"
      >
        <input
          name="product"
          type="text"
          className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md"
          placeholder="Enter product name"
        />
        <input
          name="price"
          type="text"
          className="border border-gray-300 p-2 rounded-md"
          placeholder="Enter product price"
        />
        <button className="border bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded-md">
          Add product
        </button>
      </form>

      <h2 className="font-bold p-5">list of products</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-5">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
            <p>{product.product}</p>
            <p>R$: {product.price}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

the code is the same from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6V91VeghjI&t=1040s&ab_channel=SonnySangha tutorial, I also tried to run some projects from other people in github, but all of them get the same error, I suspect servers action stopped working in nextjs13?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Node version 18. Updated to the version 20 and it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).